# When the bounty goes away?

Tags: discussion

In this questions, [Are the Minecraft animations hardcoded into the game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18023/are-the-minecraft-animations-hardcoded-into-the-game) why the bounty is still there? Shouldn't it go away, when the answer has been selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounty awards are no longer tied to accepted answer in any way.

See the blog post: [**Improvements to the Bounty System**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/)

If you are the bounty owner, you can award the bounty to a particular answer by simply clicking the bounty amount icon that appears next to each answer, as pictured below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bounties are selected independently of the accepted answer.